# how to tell if a factor has no value R

Tags: r

Here is a sample of what the data looks like. I need to replace all those empty spaces with NA so that `as.Date(dat[,i])` produces no errors

```
> dat[,i]
   [1]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  [28]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  [55]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  [82]                                                                                                    6/26/2007             7/5/2007                         7/5/2007                                                                     12/6/2007                                              2/5/2008  
 [109]            3/27/2008                        6/29/2008  9/16/2008  11/3/2008                                                                                          9/11/2008  11/24/2008 12/29/2008 11/20/2008 1/26/2009  1/8/2009                                               3/5/2009             
 [136] 4/7/2009              6/9/2009   8/23/2009  8/16/2009             9/2/2009              10/6/2009  10/14/2009 10/24/2009 10/22/2009 11/5/2009                        12/9/2009                        2/4/2010                                                          3/18/2010                       
 [163]            7/8/2010   7/7/2010   7/29/2010             10/6/2010  10/7/2010  11/18/2010                       1/12/2011  1/6/2011                                    4/5/2011   4/21/2011             5/25/2011             6/20/2011                                                                   
 [190]                       12/12/2011 2/29/2012             2/22/2012  3/7/2012              3/28/2012             5/16/2012  5/23/2012  6/14/2012                                              8/14/2012  8/16/2012  9/5/2012   9/30/2012  11/5/2012                        12/25/2012 12/27/2012 3/14/2013 
 [217]                                                        7/24/2013  7/31/2013             9/2/2013   10/16/2013            10/30/2013                                  12/13/2013            2/24/2014  3/9/2014                                               6/29/2014  6/23/2014                       
 [244]                       9/1/2014   9/22/2014  9/22/2014  11/23/2014            2/24/2015             3/17/2015  4/8/2015                         6/23/2015  6/23/2015  7/4/2015                                                                                                                           
 [271]                                                                                                                                                          ...                                                                                                                                               

[3538]                       6/29/2012  11/16/2012 11/23/2012 9/1/2012                        
916 Levels:   10/10/2008 10/10/2009 10/10/2012 10/11/2010 10/11/2013 10/1/2010 10/12/2009 10/14/2009 10/14/2010 10/14/2011 10/14/2014 10/15/2009 10/15/2014 10/16/2013 10/17/2011 10/19/2009 10/19/2010 10/19/2011 10/20/2012 10/21/2008 10/21/2010 10/21/2013 10/2/2010 10/2/2012 10/2/2013 ... 9/9/2014
```

But each cell in this has the same data type - 'factor.' `dat[,i][1] == ""` returns false for both `dat[,i][1]` and `dat[,i][3511]`, so how am I supposed to tell them apart so that I can use `apply` appropriately to place NA where it needs to go?

```
> dat[,i][1]
[1]  
916 Levels:   10/10/2008 10/10/2009 10/10/2012 10/11/2010 10/11/2013 10/1/2010 10/12/2009 10/14/2009 10/14/2010 10/14/2011 10/14/2014 10/15/2009 10/15/2014 10/16/2013 10/17/2011 10/19/2009 10/19/2010 10/19/2011 10/20/2012 10/21/2008 10/21/2010 10/21/2013 10/2/2010 10/2/2012 10/2/2013 ... 9/9/2014
> class(dat[,i][1])
[1] "factor"

> dat[,i][3511]
[1] 2/20/2012
916 Levels:   10/10/2008 10/10/2009 10/10/2012 10/11/2010 10/11/2013 10/1/2010 10/12/2009 10/14/2009 10/14/2010 10/14/2011 10/14/2014 10/15/2009 10/15/2014 10/16/2013 10/17/2011 10/19/2009 10/19/2010 10/19/2011 10/20/2012 10/21/2008 10/21/2010 10/21/2013 10/2/2010 10/2/2012 10/2/2013 ... 9/9/2014
> class(dat[,i][3511])
[1] "factor"
```

Also, trying to "go down a level" does nothing, still just a factor:

```
> dat[,i][[1]]
[1]  
916 Levels:   10/10/2008 10/10/2009 10/10/2012 10/11/2010 10/11/2013 10/1/2010 10/12/2009 10/14/2009 10/14/2010 10/14/2011 10/14/2014 10/15/2009 10/15/2014 10/16/2013 10/17/2011 10/19/2009 10/19/2010 10/19/2011 10/20/2012 10/21/2008 10/21/2010 10/21/2013 10/2/2010 10/2/2012 10/2/2013 ... 9/9/2014

> dat[,i][1][1]
[1]  
916 Levels:   10/10/2008 10/10/2009 10/10/2012 10/11/2010 10/11/2013 10/1/2010 10/12/2009 10/14/2009 10/14/2010 10/14/2011 10/14/2014 10/15/2009 10/15/2014 10/16/2013 10/17/2011 10/19/2009 10/19/2010 10/19/2011 10/20/2012 10/21/2008 10/21/2010 10/21/2013 10/2/2010 10/2/2012 10/2/2013 ... 9/9/2014
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been better to show the `dput` of the example.  Based on the OP's post, I am assuming that the levels are white space (`' '`) instead of a blank (`''`).  So, we can remove the space to convert to a `''` and then use `==`

```
library(stringr)
sapply(dat, function(x) sum(str_trim(x)=='')==1)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

---

Or use `grep`

```
sapply(lapply(dat, grepl, pattern= '^\\s+$'), all)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

#### data

```
dat <- list(factor(' ', levels=c(' ', 1:5)), factor(1:5, levels=1:5))
```

Comment: I updated my question as I realized I could have made it much clearer. It turns out all I needed to know was that the white space can be (' '). dat[,i][1] == " " returns TRUE. From there it is trivial to get what I need.

Comment: @DirkHaupt  Thanks for the feedback.